# Вывод даты из strptime Python

Tags: python, datetime

Я создал strptime строку с датой `2021-05-3`:

```
date = "2021-05-3"
main_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(main_date)
```

Но когда я вывожу эту дату, у меня она появляется в таком виде - `2021-05-03 01:00:00`, в месте со временем.
Вопрос: Могу ли я вывести только дату, но не выводить время?

Comment: `print(f"{main_date:%Y-%m-%d}")`

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось это просто

Comment: `main_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`